# Creating polygons from points with undefined order using QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, points-to-line, points2one

I have a point shapefile that contain a batch of features. I want to create polygons from these points. Each point should define a boundary of polygon.

There is an unique `"ID"` field that group points, but I don't have a order field to connect the points by order.

If I run "Points to line" tool I get some zig-zag lines and I don't want it connected in that way, I want each point to define outer boundary of each polygon. This should be done in QGIS.

I have tried Points2One Plugin but I don't have an order field to run this tool and get what I need.

Comment: Can you please show us a picture with your points? Are you aware of ["Concave hull (alpha shapes)"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#concave-hull-alpha-shapes) and ["Convex hull"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#convex-hull)?

Comment: @Taras That is exactly what I need. You can add it as an answer. Actually "Concave hull- k- nearest neighborhood" is all that I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume there is a point layer called *'end'* with its attribute table, see the image below.

[image: input]

Points are categorized by `"class"` (in your case they are grouped by the unique `"ID"` field) and spatially distributed (clustered).

I can suggest using the ["Minimum bounding geometry"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisminimumboundinggeometry) with *'convex hull'* as an enclosing geometry type and grouped by a field.

> Creates geometries which enclose the features from an input layer. The
> features can be grouped by a field. The output layer will then contain
> one feature per group value with a geometry (MBB) that covers the
> geometries of the features with matching values.

The result of this algorithm will look like

[image: result_mbg]

The same result can be achieved by means of ["Concave hull (k-nearest neighbor)"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisknearestconcavehull)

> Generates a concave hull polygon from a set of points. If the input
> layer is a line or polygon layer, it will use the vertices.

[image: result_chknn]

Why not ["Concave hull (alpha shapes)"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#concave-hull-alpha-shapes) or ["Convex hull"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#convex-hull) algorithm, because they simply do not have a grouping field.

---

**References:**

- [What is this GIS Principle Called?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/249963/what-is-this-gis-principle-called)

Comment: How do I expand this solution so that the created polygons tesselate (no gaps between polygons) the area?