# Converting lines to polygon based on matching attribute

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, polygonize

[image]In QGIS, is there a Plugin or a geoalgorithm that allows you to convert lines to polygons but incorporates a particular attribute?

I have roadside kerbs which have a field for road name, and if possible would like to convert these to polygons using the road name so we have the road carriageway, so it would also need to close the polylines.

The conversion tools I've tried don't allow for attribute selection so it means it only creates polygons where there are joining lines, such as a whole block.

Comment: Yes, check this thread https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/379411/99589

Comment: Thanks. That is close but I would need it to represent the true shape. Is there a tool to close polylines based on attributes which could then allow me to convert it to polygon?

Comment: Can you be so kind and attach some additional graphic that will elucidate your desired output?

Comment: Apologies. I've added an example. I'd like the kerb to close off and be converted to a polygon so it represents the paved roadway.

Comment: Can you please share a piece of data with us? I can suggest using the ["Geometry by expression"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) with `make_polygon($geometry)` but not sure if it can work for you.

Comment: I have uploaded a compressed shapefile http://www.filedropper.com/kerbsample with two roads, Yarrabin Drive and Osborne Drive.