# Making polygons created by Concave Hull algorithm contiguous

Tags: qgis, polygon-creation, concave-hull, tesselation

I have a set of points grouped and enclosed by a Concave Hull polygon as in this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/379117/creating-polygons-from-points-with-undefined-order-using-qgis/379411#379411). Within an outer boundary that encloses all the polygons I would like to make these polygons contiguous, that is individual polygons should expand so that each polygon shares edges with its neighbours or the enclosing boundary. Is this possible? I am using QGIS.

This what the original polygons look like:

[image: Concave hull polygons]

This is an approximation of what I want, the rules are that the number of polygons should stay the same and that all points that originally were in a particular polygon, should remain within the altered version of that polygon.

[image: Tessellated polygons]

Kadir's original solution works well but left a couple of artefacts.

[image: Artefacts]

The updated answer resolves this problem.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your map? It may help people visualize the problem better.

Answer (score 5):

- First, use one of `Densify` tools (`Densify by interval` or `Densify by count`) suitable for you to add additional vertices on polygons' edges.
- Extract the vertices to points using `Extract vertices` tool.
- Create Voronoi polygons using these points. (`Voronoi polygons` tool) > `Layer_A`
- Add a field (`POL_ID` as an example) to Voronoi polygons (`Layer_A`) to indicate intersecting Concave Hull. (`Join attribute by location` tool) > `Layer_B`
- Use `Dissolve` tool to combine polygons in `Layer_B` by `POL_ID`.

Comment: It works fine, but leaves a few artefacts, probably not too many to edit manually, but would be nice to get rid of those as well.

Comment: @KobusHerbst What is unit of data? m/inch or  degree?

Comment: It leaves artefacts because of the small number of points. So, I've edited the answer. I think it works now.

Comment: Thank you that solved the problem